# Deny creation of branch of a branch in svn

Tags: svn, branch

Is it possible to create a hook, denying, the ability to create a branch from a branch?
Allowing it only from the trunk?
If so, how would it be?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with a pre-commit hook, but you will regret this. There are times when you might create a branch off of a branch. Let's say you have a long term fix for that branch, and want to create a *feature* branch. In this case, you need to make a branch off of your branch.

Let's get to the meat of your question: How are you doing development? Too many sites (i.e. more than zero) use a *pristine trunk* methodology. The idea is that development is not done on trunk. Instead, you create a branch, do all the work on the branch, then merge that branch into trunk, and then create a new branch for the next release. One of the biggest problems is that developers *forget* to merge to trunk, and create a new branch off of trunk. It's so much easier creating the next branch off the current branch.

The pristine trunk is not a good methodology. It's complex, it is hard to do parallel development which happens when you get close to a release (especially since you don't want to create branch off of branches). And, it buys you nothing. Trunk is suppose to be the last release, but you get the same information off of tags.

Even worse, trunk cannot tell you anything except the last release (which is on `HEAD`). The previous release on trunk? You can't tell. Some files changed during the last release and others didn't. That's why you use tags. Nor, can you get any history off of trunk. Who made that change? You don't see the author of the change. Instead, you see the person who merged the branch into trunk.

If you use a pristine trunk methodology, stop.

If you're not doing the pristine trunk methodology, I'm glad to hear that. Ignore the above rant.

What you really want to do is not prevent branches of branches, but to limit who can create a branch and where they can create this branch. For example, release branches should only be done by the CM. Feature branches may be created by the team leads. You can use naming conventions to differentiate between these different branch types, or even place them under special directories. (Like `branches/releases` vs. 'branches/other`).

I have a [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that can help in this endeavor. It can limit who can create a branch, and where and what they can call the branch.

Comment: pristine trunk *is* a good methodology. It give you manageable and clean polished history (of trunk, thus: of "product") for the cost of *hardened and toughened discipline* of developers. "Branch per feature" rule the World. But branchless trunk, suggested by you, **is REALLY NIGHTMARE** for devs, PM, QAs

Comment: "create a branch, do all the work on the branch" indeed looks quite strange... The popular workflow assumes creating _many_ branches - one per feature. If features are quite small, trunk becomes a "flow of implemented features" and this really gives many benefits.

Comment: @maxim1000 - See [Practical Perforce](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101855.do) by one of the leaders in the field Laura Wingerd. It describes Perforce, but it also describes what is called the _unstable trunk_ method and why it is good.

Comment: @LazyBadger _Pristine Trunk_ doesn't give you a _cleaned up history_. You have no idea what version something was in, or who was responsible for the change. You have no idea why the changes were made since there are no comments which could include IDs from an issue tracking system. All you have is an unmarked history. Why was this change made? "Merged by a someone not really involved in development". Not a very good answer.

Comment: 1. Pristine trunk **give ME** cleaned up history: `svn log <trunk>` with well-established rules for commit message 2. I **have idea**, because I can `svn up` after reading log 3. I **have idea**, why changes was made - I see branch-name, where change was implemented and I use svn log|svn diff. 4. My policy isn't such idiotic. "Merged by QA <QANAME>, which is responsible for testing, merged from branch <BRANCHNAME> /directly mapped to issue-tracking system ticket/ on developer <DEVNAME>". **Use brain!!!**

Answer (score 0):

In my original answer, I specifically said that the *pristine trunk* methodology is flawed, I didn't mention alternatives. I did this on purpose because there are quite a few methodologies. The two most popular are called *unstable trunk* and *stream based development*.

#### Stream based development

In this, you have two separate streams: An *integration stream* and a *development stream*. In most instances, *streams* are usually implemented as branches. In Subversion, the *integration stream* can be the trunk. Developers could have multiple *development streams*, and these development streams can represent almost anything. A developer could have a one or two streams for basic development. Maybe another for a long term feature. Some places have a separate stream for each issue.

The typical workflow is:

- Developer creates a development stream from the integration stream (aka branch).
- Developer does their work.
- Developer *rebases* their stream from the *integration stream*. (aka merge from trunk to branch)
- Developer finishes testing, and *delivers* their development stream back to the *integration* stream (aka merge to trunk).
- Developer repeats the process until the project is complete, or they die.

This methodology is very common in Git where each local Git repository can be thought of a development stream and the master repository thought of as the integration stream. It is also commonly used in Agile development.

This methodology started back in the 1990s with ClearCase, then lost its popularity as Perforce, CVS and Subversion became more popular. It is now more in fashion since it seems natural with Git.

In fact, Steam based development arose even earlier with Sablime. Sablime was based upon SCCS, but with a Modification Request (MR) system tacked onto it. In Sablime, when you checked in a change, it had to be against one or more MRs. The baseline was called a *Generic* and the next *Generic* was generated by applying a set of *MRs* to the previous Generic.

#### Unstable Trunk

THe unstable trunk methodology arose around 2000 from problems with stream based development. One is that stream based development involves a lot of merging. Another, it seemed to take a lot of horsepower to implement. There's a saying in the CM world that branches are like children: If you have them, you have to take good care of them and watch them very carefully.

The *unstable trunk* methodology started coming into play with the advent of continuous integration systems like CruiseControl. In the *unstable trunk*, almost all work must be done on the trunk (or some type of integration steam). Branching is done at some undefined time where you start delivering code on the current release while wanting to continue working on the next release. Some sites, this is when you finally come up with a *Candidate Release*. At other sites, it might be when the release is *Feature Complete*. It's basically at a time when you no longer need your entire development team working on one release. In very small sites with only a couple of developers, a release branch is never created.

**By the way**, both methodologies create and release on branches. That's because in both *stream based development* and in *unstable trunk*, you may reach a point where some people are working on the 2.1 release while others are working on the 2.2 release. In *unstable trunk*, you call it a *release branch*. In *stream based development*, you simply call it another *integration stream*.

The big difference between the two is when you decide what features to add and when. In *unstable trunk*, this must be done at the beginning of a development cycle (or maybe at the beginning of an Agile Sprint). You have to since your development depends upon implementing one change issue and then the next.

In stream based development, this can be delayed until the end of the cycle. You can work on issues 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, then decide that you only want issues 1002 and 1004 to be delivered to the integration stream.

The major problem with stream based development and the reason it lost popularity was the realization that you are creating streams on code that no longer is relevant. For example, I'm working on issue 1004. Issues 1001, 1002, and 1003 have been done, but not delivered, so I'm working on a code base that doesn't include changes that other developers have done.

Plus, merging is a hassle. You will have merge conflicts which means that developers must take time off development to debug and test merges.

Stream based development also means that testing cannot take place until code is actually delivered. The later you hold off on delivering changes, the less testing of any sort can take place.

There are ways to get around these issues. Agile development chops up development into sprints and forces delivery at the end of each sprint. A release might consist of 3 to 4 sprints with a final 5th sprint for cleanup.

This pushes stream based development to be more like unstable trunk, but you can still pick and choose during the end of a sprint. For example, a developer is working on a particular issue when the team realizes that the coding isn't going the way it should. There may be a decision not to include this particular stream in this sprint and maybe think of a new way to reimplement that feature.

Stream based development is also more friendly to code reviews since the code is committed, but isn't in the *delivery stream* yet.

The unstable trunk's main advantage is simplicity, and forces developers to take *smaller bites* when making changes. A particular change might be implemented in several stages instead of all at once. It also makes it easier for continuous integration and for QA testing since QA testing can take place at almost anywhere during development.

*Stream based development* is more popular with developers and project managers. Developers can work on changes the way they want, and project mangers can hold off on what features to deliver until the end of the release.\

*Unstable trunk* is more popular with QA, tech leads, and CM. QA can do testing a lot earlier and find issues before the rush to release. CM likes it because there is less branches to track, technical managers like it because it involves less oversight on development.

Neither of these methods are *automatic* and different tools tend to lend themselves to different practices. CVS is useless with stream based development since branching and merging is very expensive. Yet, it works very nicely with *unstable trunk*. Git works great with *stream based development*, but simply becomes a burden when used with *unstable trunk*.

CVS, Perforce, and Subversion tend to work best with *unstable trunk*. Although Subversion branching is a minimal cost, merging is still a rather sloppy operation. Git tends to work with *stream based development*.